# Prevent new user inside docker container from accessing root owned files

Tags: docker

I'm running a simple flask app inside a docker container. At the end of the Dockerfile I want to add a new user that doesn't have permissions to read files owned by the docker root user. But when I do that the new user *sandbox* can still access `/etc/passwd` and all files copied before it's creation like *app.py*.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /var/www

COPY app.py .
RUN pip3 install flask

RUN useradd sandbox
USER sandbox

CMD [ "python3", "app.py" ]
```

App.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root_handler():
    return "Hello: {} {}".format(getpass.getuser(), '<3')

@app.route('/read')
def read_source():
    with open("/etc/passwd", "r") as f:
        return f.read() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Do I have to manually set all permissions with `RUN chmod ...` or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: The `/etc/passwd` file is almost always world-readable (owned by `root:root`, mode 0644); the `/etc/shadow` file with actual user passwords shouldn't be readable (mode 0600).

Comment: did you read this docs reference? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add Maybe using `--chown`